# how use alias in sqlachemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a sql query as follows

```
select cloumn1,column2,count(column1) as c 
from Table1 where user_id='xxxxx' and timestamp > xxxxxx
group by cloumn1,column2
order by  c desc limit 1;
```

And I successed in write the sqlalchemy equvalent

```
result = session.query(Table1.field1,Table1.field2,func.count(Table1.field1)).filter(
    Table1.user_id == self.user_id).filter(Table1.timestamp > self.from_ts).group_by(
    Table1.field1,Travelog.field2).order_by(desc(func.count(Table1.field1))).first()
```

But I want to avoid using `func.count(Table1.field1)` in the `order_by` clause.

How can I use alias in sqlalchemy? Can any one show any example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aliases are for tables; columns in a query are given a label instead. This trips me up from time to time too.

You can go about this two ways. It is sufficient to store the `func.count()` result is a local variable first and reuse that:

```
field1_count = func.count(Table1.field1)

result = session.query(Table1.field1, Table1.field2, field1_count).filter(
    Table1.user_id == self.user_id).filter(Table1.timestamp > self.from_ts).group_by(
    Table1.field1, Travelog.field2).order_by(desc(field1_count)).first()
```

The SQL produced would still be the same as your own code would generate, but at least you don't have to type out the `func.count()` call twice.

To give this column an explicit label, call the [`.label()` method](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.label) on it:

```
field1_count = func.count(Table1.field1).label('c')
```

and you can then use that same label *string* in the `order_by` clause:

```
result = session.query(Table1.field1, Table1.field2, field1_count).filter(
    Table1.user_id == self.user_id).filter(Table1.timestamp > self.from_ts).group_by(
    Table1.field1, Travelog.field2).order_by(desc('c')).first()
```

or you could use the `field1_count.name` attribute:

```
result = session.query(Table1.field1, Table1.field2, field1_count).filter(
    Table1.user_id == self.user_id).filter(Table1.timestamp > self.from_ts).group_by(
    Table1.field1, Travelog.field2).order_by(desc(field1_count.name)).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also using the [c](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Join.c) which is an alias of the column attribute but in this case a label will work fine as stated.

Will also point out that the filter doesn't need to be used multiple times can pass comma separated criterion.

```
result = (session.query(Table1.field1, Table1.field2,
          func.count(Table1.field1).label('total'))
         .filter(Table1.c.user_id == self.user_id, Table1.timestamp > self.from_ts)
         .group_by(Table1.field1,Table1.field2)
         .order_by(desc('total')).first())
```